# how to fix my 'Three column footer layout' as well as text-stylings

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to stylise my text in CSS and here's what gets displayed.

[image: screeny]

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
<title></title>
</head>
<body class="wrapper">
<!-- header for: ALL PAGES --->
<header id="header">

</header>
<!-- end header for: ALL PAGES --->
<!-- navigation bar for: ALL PAGES --->
<nav>

</nav>
<!-- end navigation bar for: ALL PAGES --->
<!-- paragraph for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->
<section id="welcome_p">

</section>
<!-- end paragraph for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->
<!-- images for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->
<section id="plan_options">

</section>
<!-- end images for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->

<!-- footer for: ALL PAGES --->

<footer id="footer">
<div id="left_side_footer">
<p class="footer_heading">About</p>
</br></br>
<a href="#" class="footer_link">
<span class="footer_paragraph">Get to Know John</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="footer_link">
<span class="footer_paragraph">Moon Lit Disco's</span>
</a>

</div>

<div id="middle_of_footer">
<p class="footer_heading">Terms and Policies</span>
</br></br>
<a href="#" class="footer_link">
<span class="footer_paragraph">Cookie Policy</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="footer_link">
<span class="footer_paragraph">Terms and Conditions</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="footer_link">
<span class="footer_paragraph">Privacy Policy</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="footer_link">
<span class="footer_paragraph">Copyright and Trademark</span>
</a>

</div>

<div id="right_side_footer">
<p class="footer_heading">Website</p>
</br></br>
<a href="#" class="footer_link">
<span class="footer_paragraph">Feedback</span>
</a>
</div>

<div id="copyright">
<p class="legal_paragraph">Logo / site design: <a href="#">Trey Taylor</a> and <a href="#">Charlie Wubs</a></p>
<p class="legal_paragraph">&copy2014 Moon Lit Disco's</p>
<p class="legal_paragraph">Version:2014.1.0</p>
</div>

</footer>
<!-- end footer for: ALL PAGES --->
</body>
</html>
```

any my CSS:

```
/* SECTIONS */

/* CLASSES */

.legal_paragraph{
font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
text-align:right;
font-size:10px;
color:black;
padding:1px;
}

.footer_paragraph{
font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
font-size:1em;
color:black;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}

.footer_link{
text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_heading{

display:inline;
font-family:"Century Gothic";
font-size:17px;
color:black;
text-decoration:underline;
background-color:white;
display:inline;
width=100%; 
} 

.fp{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
font-size:1em;
display:block;
font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

/* STYLE */

a{
text-decoration:none;
}

#footer a.footer_link:hover span{
   border-bottom:1px solid black; 
   border-top:1px solid black;
   width:100%
   }

#line_break{

}

#left_side_footer{
display:table-cell;
float:left;
padding-right:360px;
padding-bottom:30px;
} 

#right_side_footer{
display:table-cell;
float:right;
}

#middle_of_footer{
display:table-cell;
float:center;
}
```

What I want:

The text to be not underlined, same size and font (for some reason it doesn't do that)
get it so it is all inline
get that legal stuff below it all

Any help would be must appreicated!

Comment: Please give a suitable title for your question!

Comment: `width=100%;` is not valid CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Aibrean  know, I forgot to take it out when I started (new to HTML and CSS so was experimenting, forgot to take it out).

Comment: If you haven't already, install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), it will help you understand what css was applied to each element of your page.  Intro on CSS debugging in Firebug [here](https://getfirebug.com/css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text not to be underlined, then you need to style the *anchor*.

Example:

```
footer a {
text-decoration:none;
}

.footer_link a {
font-size:1em;
}
```

Since your footer is an HTML5 element, you don't really need an ID of #footer. Semantically, anyway.

You also don't need spans. You can just use the parent class to style the font size.

You're also missing a closing paragraph tag, which might be why it's not taking the paragraph styles.

Cleaning up your code, your HTML should be more like this (head area is removed, but it's fine):

```
<body class="wrapper">
    <!-- header for: ALL PAGES --->
    <header></header>
    <!-- end header for: ALL PAGES --->
    <!-- navigation bar for: ALL PAGES --->
    <nav></nav>
    <!-- end navigation bar for: ALL PAGES --->
    <!-- paragraph for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->
    <section id="welcome_p"></section>
    <!-- end paragraph for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->
    <!-- images for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->
    <section id="plan_options"></section>
    <!-- end images for: THIS PAGE ONLY --->
    <!-- footer for: ALL PAGES --->
    <footer>
        <div class="column">
            <p class="footer_heading">About</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer_link">Get to Know John</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer_link">Moon Lit Disco's</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p class="footer_heading">Terms and Policies</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer_link">Cookie Policy</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer_link">Terms and Conditions</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer_link">Privacy Policy</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer_link">Copyright and Trademark</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p class="footer_heading">Website</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer_link"> Feedback</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="copyright">
            <p>Logo / site design: <a href="#">Trey Taylor</a> and <a href="#">Charlie Wubs</a>
            </p>
            <p>&copy; 2014 Moon Lit Disco's</p>
            <p>Version:2014.1.0</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
   .column {
    font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:black;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:13px;
    width:30%;
}

.column a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

.column ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:-40px;
}

.footer_heading {
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    font-size:17px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:white;
}

#copyright {
    clear:both;
    font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:10px;
    color:black;
    padding:1px;
}

#copyright a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6o9wg43/

Comment: did not fix my problem

Comment: I'm editing the answer...there are a lot of issues with your code/css.

Comment: do you mind chatting and explaing where? bit of a newb at the moment haha

Comment: That's fine. Let me know where.

Answer (score 2):

Without doing all the work for you something like this should work.

Will need some styling from here, suggest looking at http://www.codecademy.com/

HTML

```
<footer>
<ul class="left">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Get to know John</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Moon Lit Disco's</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="left">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Get to know John</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Moon Lit Disco's</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="left">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Get to know John</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Moon Lit Disco's</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clearLeft">
<p>Logo / site design: <a href="#">Trey Taylor</a> and <a href="#">Charlie Wubs</a></p>
<p>&copy; 2014 Moon Lit Disco's</p>
<p>Version:2014.1.0</p>
</div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.left{
    float:left;
}
.clearLeft{
    clear:left;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Should get you started :)

Comment: Thanks Matt! Before I accept, may I ask a few things just so I know it rather than copy? 

I'd like to know why all the <ul>'s would be the same class? In my head it would make sense to do them seperately to organise them left, right and center?

Comment: Np, if you think of them as 3 boxes, you want them all to sit next to each other in a row.
Float left makes them do just that, float to the left in a line. The clear below stops this floating so the copyright part ends up below them. 
This is essentially the easiest to line them up. No need to give them separate id's as they all want to do the same thing. Plus you then have less/simpler code which is always a good thing.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Your help is very much appreciated!